# calculate $\small\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{2}{n^{2}}+...+\frac{n}{n^{2}}\big) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need help calculating 
  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{2}{n^{2}}+...+\frac{n}{n^{2}}\right) = ?$$

Comment: Hint: can you re-express $1+2+\ldots +n$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
$$1+2+\cdots+n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}2$$
Hence, we need
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac1{n^2} + \dfrac2{n^2} + \cdots + \dfrac{n}{n^2}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}\right) = \dfrac12$$

Answer (score 4):

$$1+2+\ldots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ which implies that $$\frac1{n^2}+\frac2{n^2}+\ldots+\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2n^2}=\frac12+\frac{1}{2n}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

- First possibility: Rewrite this
  $$
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}
  $$
  and apply results you know (?) on Riemann sums with the function $f\colon x\in [0,1]\mapsto x$.
- Second possibility:
  Explicitly compute $\sum_{k=1}^n k$. Now, you can divide by $n^2$ and take the limit.

  > In more detail: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Remark: The grey area at the end is a "spoiler," which gives extra information about the second hint. Place your mouse over it to reveal the text.

Comment: The hidden answer is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{2}{n^{2}}+...+\frac{n}{n^{2}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{m}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{2}=\frac{1+0}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: It looks more like an answer than a hint.

Comment: @Shadock No it isn't because I didn't say why my sum is equal to $\frac{n+1}{2n}$!

Comment: It looks more not it is ;)